# Saving results from getOutlier function in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, outliers

Back again with a question that has me stumped. This is
is slightly similar to this post: [How can I see multiple variable's outlier in one boxplot using R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45163254/how-can-i-see-multiple-variables-outlier-in-one-boxplot-using-r/45165215#45165215), but I am trying to iterate over more than just a column.

My hopefully somewhat reproducible code follows:

```
library(extremevalues)
data(cars)
result<-list()
nFits<-list()
methodz<-c("I","II")
dists<-c("exponential","normal","lognormal","pareto","weibull")
for (i in seq_along(methodz)){
    for(j in seq_along(dists)){
        for(k in 1:ncol(cars)){
           nFits[[i]]   <-getOutliers(cars[k],
                       method=methodz[i],distribution=dists[j])$nFit
      result<-nFits
     }
   }
}
```

My goal is to examine the extreme values of each of my continuous outcomes to determine the most appropriate course of action. For each variable, I want to run the getOutliers function for both methods types, and for all 5 distributions, and save nFit, yMin, and yMax to a data frame for review. nFits, yMin, and yMax are all output from getOutliers.

I know that I am not subscripting each of the list objects correctly as I keep getting an improper number of subscripts error. Any advice you could offer would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create a nested `list` and then assign the output of the `getOutliers` to it

```
methodz <- c("I","II")
dists <- c("exponential","normal","lognormal","pareto","weibull")
nFits <- replicate(length(methodz), vector("list", length(dists)), 
                     simplify = FALSE)
for (i in seq_along(methodz)){
    for(j in seq_along(dists)){
        for(k in seq_along(cars)){
           nFits[[i]][[j]][k]  <- getOutliers(cars[[k]],
                       method=methodz[i],distribution=dists[j])$nFit

     }
   }
}
```

Comment: This does the trick! I'll have to look into nested lists. Thank you akrun!